# CI 3 requested url not found

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm new in CI 3. I want to view another page when the button is clicked. I'm using Wamp server. in my root folder (www) I name my project sampleproject.

In my `routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'user';
```

**Controller file** name is User.php

```
public function login_user(){
    $this-load-view('welcome_message');
}
```

And in my **view**

```
<form action="/user/login_user" method="POST" role="form">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
</form>
```

When I click the button in the URL it shows http://localhost/user/login_user

http://localhost/sampleproject -> show the index but when I enter http://localhost/sampleproject/user/login_user -> says requested URL not found.

Why can't I view another page?

Comment: Did you set `.htaccess` to remove `index.php` ..?

Comment: project name is `sample` or `sampleproject`?

Comment: Try this `http://localhost/sampleproject/index.php/user/login_user`

Answer (score 0):

In `APPPATH.'config/config.php'` you should set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sampleproject/'
```

Eventually, in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteBase /sampleproject/
```